# Chrome app "onSuspend" being called, why?

Tags: google-chrome-app

According to [Google's app lifecycle docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_lifecycle)

> When the event page has no executing JavaScript, no pending callbacks, and no open windows, the runtime unloads the event page and closes the app.

I am seeing in my app that an `onSuspend` is being triggered, which also has the side effect of invalidating any `FileEntry` or `DirectoryEntry` references (an as-of-yet undocumented "feature"), only the `onSuspend` is triggered when I still have pending callbacks and open windows. Does anybody know which other conditions will trigger an `onSuspend`? Does it have to do with the app using too much memory?

It makes sense that `onSuspend` will be called when the event/background page has no activity and there are no windows open, but when else would `onSuspend` be called?

Is there a secret permission that I can use to disable `onSuspend` from being called? A background permission API in the works?

Answer (score 2):

It should not be triggered if you have open windows unless something atypical is under way, like the user upgrading chrome.

If you are seeing onSuspend events at other times, that sounds like a bug. Please report at crbug.com with steps to reproduce.